# TCL/TK bad window or path name when adding a button

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I keep getting "bad window or path name" when trying to add the first button. And i do not have a clou why... I'm pretty shure to have used the same syntax elsewhere without problems...

```
tk::toplevel ".topbox"
wm title .topbox "SnapShooter"
wm geometry .topbox 200x200+0+0
wm resizable .topbox 0 0
button .topbox.btn_1  -text "Destroy"  -width 150 -background  green -command   [destroy .topbox ]                                                   
pack .topbox.btn_1                                                
button .topbox.btn_2  -text "Shoot Image"  -width 150 -background  green -command [ puts something]
pack  .topbox.btn_2
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.tcl/i6LjeaPChlk as well as here: http://wiki.tcl.tk/15242 ; these were the first 2 results when I googled

Comment: Sorry, maybe i need more coffe: But my windowname starts with a "." and as a toplevel window I do not have to "pack" it either. By the way: I also found these two sites before i asked ;-)

Comment: It's ok, answers aren't really answers if they are just links, but I thought I could help you with the links if you hadn't found them, so I at least made the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you give a command, such as `button ...`, the Tcl interpreter attempts to substitute things like variables and commands as far as possible. This means that if (like in this case) you create a button and set its command with this invocation

```
button .top.btn -command [destroy .top]
```

Tcl executes the command `destroy .top` as part of executing your `button` invocation (and inserts the result value of the execution as a command string passed to the command option).  You don't want that to happen (usually, and certainly not in this case, as it saws off the branch your GUI is sitting on), so you need to prevent Tcl from substituting this particular part of the invocation.

If you don't need to substitute *anything* in the command string that you pass to the command option, you can write it like this

```
button .top.btn -command {destroy .top}
```

or (a little more fragile)

```
button .top.btn -command \[destroy .top]
```

but in some cases you need to substitute some part of the command string without executing the command. This won't work:

```
set w .top
button $w.btn -command {destroy $w}
```

since that would have the button try to execute the unsubstituted command string `destroy $w`.

In such cases, it's usually sufficient to wrap the command string in `list`:

```
set w .top
button $w.btn -command [list destroy $w]
```

So, instead of

```
button .topbox.btn_1 \
    -text "Destroy" \
    -width 150 \
    -background green \
    -command [destroy .topbox]
```

you should write

```
button .topbox.btn_1 \
    -text "Destroy" \
    -width 150 \
    -background green \
    -command [list destroy .topbox]
```

or possibly give the command option as

```
    -command {destroy .topbox}
```

since you don't need to substitute anything.

Comment: Thanks ! Your right, my only differnce was the type of brace, because I had something else in there before which actually needed substitution.

Comment: @Lumpi If you're thinking about anything more complicated than what you can do with a simple literal or what you can make easily with `list`, use a helper procedure. It's the easiest way by far.